# Descarga de fichero de directorio Struts 2

Tags: jsp, archivo, response, struts2

Necesito descargar un fichero de un directorio a través de un JSP en Struts 2, pero me da un nullPointer el HttpServletResponse, justo en la línea que pone OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
private HttpServletResponse response;

public String downloadFile() throws Exception {
    
    String fileName = request.getParameter("fileNameDownload");
    String fileType = request.getParameter("typeFile");
    File file = new File(pathFile + fileName);
            
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    response.setContentType("text/xml");
    response.setHeader("cache-control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
    char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
        stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    out.write(stringBuilder.toString().getBytes());
    log.debug("ESCRITO");
}
```

Comment: response es null. Con ese trozo de código, sin saber dónde está declarada o inicializada esa variable, no podemos averiguar mucho más. ¿Puedes poner la firma del método, o más información de esta clase?

Comment: ok, ya está editado el código, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Struts2 hay dos maneras de obtener la instancia HttpServletResponse en un *Action*:

En el método que gestiona una petición:

```
public String downloadFile() throws Exception {
    HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
    ...
}
```

Implementando en la clase la interfaz *ResponseAware*:

```
public class LocaleAction implements ServletResponseAware{

    HttpServletResponse response;

    
    public String downloadFile() {
       ...
    }

    public void setServletResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        this.response = response;
    }
    public HttpServletResponse getServletResponse() {
        return this.response;
    }
}
```

En el trozo de código que has puesto no me queda claro si estás intentando la segunda opción pero se te olvidó crear los setters y getters porque no estás implementando ResponseAware, pero viendo que la variable `response` es un atributo del objeto y no una variable local, asumo que es así.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo he solucionado con tu respuesta.

Comment: Puedes "aceptar" la respuesta y así la pregunta quedará marcada como respondida, si quieres